# Как установить ожидание нажатия клавиши без цикла while True? Python

Tags: python, while

Приложение на Python работает в свернутом режиме, ожидая нажатия определенных клавиш. При нажатии, происходит выполнение соответствующего кода. Все отлично работает, но проблема в том, что программа должна быть постоянно запущена и свернута в трее, ожидая нажатия кнопки в цикле **`while True:`**
Это сильно грузит систему.

**Как можно сохранить логику работы программы, избавившись от цикла?**

**Код:**

```
import keyboard

while True:
     if keyboard.is_pressed('F7'):
          #Действия, при нажатии на кнопку F7

     if keyboard.is_pressed('F5'):
          #Действия, при нажатии на кнопку F5

#И так далее
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А поставить хук, который будет вызывать нужную функцию при нажатии нужной кнопки вас устроит?

```
keyboard.hook_key(key, callback, suppress=False)
```

Comment: Это именно то, что я искал! Спасибо. Почему-то в документации я этого не видел...

Comment: @denisnumb, тогда посмотрите еще `keyboard.on_press_key(key, callback, suppress=False)` и т.п. функции, которые содержат колбеки, может они вас утроят еще больше

Comment: Как можно решить проблему того, что при однократном нажатии функция успевает вызваться несколько раз?

Comment: @denisnumb - есть 2 способа - 1) устанавливайте флаг, который будете проверять в колбек-функции и который будете сбрасывать при отпускании кнопки, 2_ повесить колбек на отпускание кнопки - но с вариантом 2) есть проблемы - если долго давить на кнопку - ничего происходить не будет (только при отжатии), поэтому вариант 1) как по мне наиболее приемлемый

Comment: Удалось решить проблему установив `suppress` на `True`